# Cannot read the property of _id undefined

Tags: jquery, html

> script.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

I get this undefined property of `_id` I am trying to do a put method on the UI below is my front end js and html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name content="width=device-width">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<head>
<body>
  <title>Student Attendance</title>
  <header>
    <h1>Students</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Additional Student</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="newForm">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="_id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ID</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="int" autocomplete="on">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="role_num" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">role number</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role_num" autocomplete="on">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">first name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" autocomplete="on">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">last name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" autocomplete="on">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="marks" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">marks</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marks" autocomplete="on">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button id="newStudent" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Student</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">End</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editStudentModal2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Update Student</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="updateForm">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">ID</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="student_id">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="role_num" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Role Number</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role_num">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="first_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="marks" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Marks</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Marks">
              </div>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">End</button>
            <button id="studentUpdate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=#exampleModal2>Update Student</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="newStudent" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Student</button>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead style="background:#ddd;" class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Role Number</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
        <th>Option</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="students">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showStudents('students');

  $("#newStudent").click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    let data = {
      _id: $($("#newForm")[0].int).val(),
      role_num: $($("#newForm")[0].role_num).val(),
      first_name: $($("#newForm")[0].first_name).val(),
      last_name: $($("#newForm")[0].last_name).val(),
      marks: $($("#newForm")[0].marks).val(),
    }

    $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#newForm").toggle();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:3200/students/addStudent",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
    }).always(function(data) {
      console.log('always', data);
      showStudents();
    });
  });

  $('#studentUpdate').click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    let update = {
      _id: $($("#updateForm")[0].int).val(),
      role_num: $($("#updateForm")[0].role_num).val(),
      first_name: $($("#updateForm")[0].first_name).val(),
      last_name: $($("#updateForm")[0].last_name).val(),
      marks: $($("#updateForm")[0].marks).val(),
    }

    $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
    $("#updateForm").toggle();

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3200/students/updateStudent",
      method: 'PUT',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: update,
    }).always(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      showStudents();
    });
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.edit-student', function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    $('#exampleModal2').modal('show'); //open modal
    var student_id = $(this).data('studentid');
    //populate newForm
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:3200/students/" + student_id,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        const student = response[0];
        $('#student_id').val(student._id);
        $('#role_num').val(student.role_num);
        $('#first_name').val(student.first_name);
        $('#last_name').val(student.last_name);
        $('#Marks').val(student.marks);
      }
    });
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.deleteStudent', function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    var student_id = $(this).data('studentid');
    console.log(a);
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:3200/students/deleteStudent",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        _id: student_id
      },
      dataType: 'json',
    }).always(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      showStudents();
      confirm("You want to delete this");
    });
  });
});

function showStudents() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3200/students",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      $('#students').empty();
      $.each(response, function(i, student) {
        const text = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + student._id + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.role_num + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.first_name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.last_name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + student.marks + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger deleteStudent\"  data-studentid=" + student._id + ">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger edit-student' data-toggle='modal' data-target1='#exampleModal2' data-studentid=" + student._id + ">Edit</button></td>";
        $("#students").append(text);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

So the issue is with my edit-student function but I need to know how student._id is undefined.Also just let me know guys where I have gone wrong with the error I made

Comment: Do `console.log(student)` to see what properties the object actually has

Comment: @Roy McCrossan nothing comes up

Comment: That sounds like your problem then - the object you're calling `_id` on is null/undefined